# Desabilitar link com jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Boa tarde galera,
Eu estou tendo um problema ao tentar desabilitar um link utilizando jquery.
O problema é o seguinte,
Existe uma tabela que lista os tipos de papéis que um usuário pode possuir no sistema que apresenta as informações dessa forma :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

os botões das opções possuem as classes btnView, btnEdit e btnRemove respectivamente 
até aí blz.
Eu quero que as opções de edição e remoção seja feita apenas por usuários administradores.
o meu controller está me retornando 1, caso o usuário logado possua permissão de amin  e null caso contrário e adicionando esse valor em um input do tipo hidden. Ele já está me retornando certo a permissão porém, no javascript, quando eu mando ele desabilitar o botão caso o usuário não seja um administrador nada acontece. 
o meu arquivo está da seguinte forma:
**HTML**

```
   <a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm btnShow" data-id="{{$papel->id}}" >
      <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
   </a>
   <a href="#" class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm btnEdit"   data-toggle="modal"data-target="#create" data-id="{{$papel->id}}" id="btnEdit">
      <i class="material-icons" style="color:white">edit</i>
   </a>
   <a href="#" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#dropPapel" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm btnRemove" >
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

       if($('#userAdmin').val()!=1){
        console.log('não é admin')
        $('.btnRemove').attr('disabled','disabled')
        $('.btnShow').attr('disabled','disabled')
        $('.btnEdit').attr('disabled','disabled') 
    }
</script>
```

Eu não consigo achar o problema, se eu tento ocultar o link eu consigo, porém se eu tento desabilitar não, nem mesmo se atribuir na tag a propriedade disabled ou colocar attr('disabled',true) não funciona. Eu já havia utilizado essa mesma forma de desabilitar em outros lugares sem nenhum problema, porém nessa parte não está funcionando. O código está caindo na condição certa, está imprimindo no console a mensagem que eu mandei, porém não desabilita os links 
 
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz eu ficaria muito agradecido.
Desde já obrigado

Comment: `console.log` é executado? Lembre-se de fazer a validação no lado do servidor, pois esse `disabled` pode ser contornado muito facilmente através do inspetor do navegador.

Comment: sim sim, ele imprime no console a mensagem mas não desabilita os links

Comment: Já tentou com .prop() e não com .attr()? Para as versões mais novas do jQuery o mais indicado é que use .prop()

Comment: ja fiz isso também

Comment: Vc está utilizando algum framework Javascript?

Comment: Não seria melhor remover os links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você está usando um *event handler* para escutar os cliques nos links. Se estiver utilizando uma versão 1.7 ou superior, utilize o método `.off()` para remover os eventos de click dos elementos:

```
$('.btnRemove, .btnShow, .btnEdit').off('click');
```

Caso esteja utilizando uma versão anterior a 1.7, use `.unbind():`

```
$('.btnRemove, .btnShow, .btnEdit').unbind('click');
```

---

Se você não especificar um evento no `.off()`, irá remover todos os eventos aos quais o elemento pode estar vinculado:

```
$('.btnRemove, .btnShow, .btnEdit').off();
```

Vou mostrar um exemplo utilizando `.off()`:

```js
$(".btnEdit, .btnRemove, .btnShow").click(function(){
   console.log("link clicado");
});

function removeEvento(){
   $(".btnEdit, .btnRemove, .btnShow").off();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btnEdit" href="#">Editar</a><br>
<a class="btnRemove" href="#">Remover</a><br>
<a class="btnShow" href="#">Mostrar</a>
<br><br>
Clique no botão abaixo para remover os cliques dos links acima:<br>
<button onclick="removeEvento()">Remover click</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Cara o seu problema é que um `<a>` não tem o atributo global `disabled`, então na adianta setar `disabled` nele que não vai funcionar.

`disabled` é para `input`, `buttons` e outros elementos de formulário, não para link.

Seu jQuery está funcionando e setando o attr() no elemento, só que ele continua "clicável" pq o HTML não entende o que é um `disabled="disabled"` em um link (elemento `<a>`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a lista dos **Atributos Permitidos** na tag `<a>`, e o atributo `disabled` não está na lista! https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

---

Veja que se vc trocar o `<a>` por um `<button>` ele vai vai ficar `disabled` já o `<a>` não.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('#userAdmin').val() != 1) {
   console.log('não é admin')
   $('.btnRemove').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
   $('.btnShow').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
   $('.btnEdit').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<button class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" data-id="{{$papel->id}}" id="btnEdit">
 <i class="material-icons">isso é um button</i>
</button>

<a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dropPapel" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm btnRemove">
 <i class="material-icons">isso é link</i>
</a>
```

---

**Dica**

Se vc quer manter o link, vc pode "desabilita-lo" usando algumas propriedades CSS como `pointer-event:none`, e `user-select:none`. Além disso tb indico setar a propriedade `tabindex="-1"` para o elemento não ser acessível por teclado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#userAdmin').val() != 1) {
    console.log('não é admin')
    $('.desabilitado').css({"background-color": "yellow", "cursor": "default", "pointer-events": "none", "user-select": "none"}).attr('tabindex', -1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="X" class="desabilitado">link "desabilitado"</a><br>
<a href="X" class="normal">link "normal"</a>
```

Comment: Trocar a tag `<a>` por `<button>` seria ideal dentro do contexto do código dele para manter a semântica.

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva sim concordo, inclusive seria bom tb adicionar outros atributos caso ele mantenha o link como aria-label etc... para tentar contornar esse problema de um "link desabled", mas como não sei das limitações do escopo e do projeto que ele tem lá de essa sugestão que acredito que resolva por hora